# Running Python exe from command line

Tags: python

I am very new to Python so it is wasting my time. But it is a simple problem. I have a python program as follow.

```
import time
import os
import subprocess

def camera_play(cmd):

  if cmd == 1:
     cmd = 'raspistill --nopreview -w 640 -h 480 -q 5 -o /tmp/stream/pic.jpg -tl 100 -t 9999999 -th 0:0:0 &'
     pid = subprocess.call(cmd, shell = True)

     cmd1 = 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib mjpg_streamer -i "input_file.so -f /tmp/stream -n pic.jpg" -o "output_http.so -w /usr/local/www"'

     pid1 = subprocess.call(cmd1, shell = True)
  elif cmd == 0:
     pid.kill()
     pid1.kill()
```

I made it exe program using `Pyinstaller`. How to run that exe from command line with input argument.
I run like

```
camera_play 1
camera_play -i 1
```

It doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: `*.exe` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/...`? How is that supposed to work? Which platform are you on, Linux or Windows?

Comment: I am running in Linux. It works. I tested already.

Comment: You can't run an `*.exe` file on Linux, that's an executable format specific to MS Windows.

Comment: Install wine and then ,try with `wine camera_play 1`

Comment: No I like to run as for example ls command. Just type the command.

Comment: an executable must be in your PATH to be executable. typically in /usr/bin, or /opt/ something, or ~/bin... or you run it by `./camera_play 1` if it is in the same directory as you.

Comment: @user1350772; if no argument, I can type camera_play and it runs. I tested already. Now is with input argument.

Comment: and anyway, you don't need Pyinstaller. chmod u+x and #!/bin/python at the beginning of the file are sufficient

Comment: would you be kind enough as to detail what you mean by `It doesn't work`?

Comment: also, I don't see the part where you call the function, and where you gather the inputs from the user

Comment: @njzk2; yes I think I missed the part to gather the inputs from the user. How to do that? I think cmd is input argument and I use cmd. Is it not enough?

Comment: you define a function. but the function is not automatically called. also, you apparently rely on keeping the `pid` so you can kill the process. but this variable will not be kept across executions. you'd have to write it down somewhere.

Comment: @njzk2; now I know why I see #!/bin/python at the beginning of all python program.

Comment: @njzk2; thanks, the program still not correct.

Comment: i don't quite understand the use of python, also.

Comment: note that in addition to executing the script with a hash-bang at the start you could simply use 'python camera_play'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are running under Linux you don't have to create an exe file.
Your code won't do anything as there is only a function but it is never call.

You must use this function after its definition.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    import...

    def camera_play(cmd):
        ...

    if len(sys.argv)>1:
        cmd = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        cmd = WHAT YOU WANT???
    camera_play(cmd)
```

To call your script from command line you have two possibilities:

```
    python myscript
```

or

```
    ./myscript
```

Note that you cmd seems to accept 1 or 0 that is strange! and if 0 the pid vars won't exist!
You have to seriously think to what you are trying to do.
You can also considere using subprocess.Popen

Comment: Thanks. Since I am running the program from my remote device, I need to make exe and put it in the usr/bin. I'll learn python later. Now is I need to finish streaming media first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link ( http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm ), you have two issues:

1. There is no main in your program
2. You are not processing command line arguments

You need something like this at the end of the file:

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
      camera_play(sys.argv[1])
```

This combined with the #!/bin/python at the top of your file with correct unix executable permissions should allow you to run it from the command line with arguments.